# Multi-Front end with 1 Back-end API

Tags: angular, laravel

My customer has some requirement: whitelabel system. There are 1 back-end API server and multi Front-end 
Front-end build on Angular
Back-end build on Laravel

example: Front-end 1 with logo and company 1, When customer visit to front-end 1 to register account, back-end will create account and send email to customer "hello customer, we are brand 1"

I have question: How to storage 'Company name' and Logo? I have 2 solutions:
1. Storage logo and company name in code,
2. Get logo and company from API backend server

What the best solution?
thanks

System structure like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Two approaches:**

1. If you have different domains for each customer/brand, do not store images in the backend, because logo is the first thing you want the user to see even before any api calls are made from browser.
2. If you have same domain but using some kind of login/authorization for customer identification, still store the logo in frontend with html and js files. So it loads right after login, and network load on backend server can be reduces.

Answer (score 0):

If there are going to be a lot of companies, you should create a database table with all the information you want to send or display. .. like the companyname, description, dailymessage, etc.... And add a column  to store the URL where the logo image is located. You can easily modify these values with querys without changing any of the code.
If you want to include the logo image inside the email, you will need to craft this email. You first will query the database to fetch the company data: name, message, url. Craf email and write the URL inside html tags